# Prepopulating forms via URL when parameters are already set

Tags: php, forms, url, href

I would like to generate a link to this website where certain parameters are already set. The trouble is: there are already parameters set in the URL (i.e., the pin code which identifies the dealership).

Here's the URL to the form:

> https://www.youcangetacar.com/formstep2.php?Pin=A186&Submit=Submit+To+Final+Step

I have tried the following.

> https://www.youcangetacar.com/formstep2.php?Pin=A186**&fname=ASDF**&Submit=Submit+To+Final+Step

I've also tried adding it before the pin, after the submit. Do I have to set *ALL* the parameters for this to work? Do I have to specify the formset? I've seen this done using arrays; could that work?

Also, it should be noted that I do not have access to this web page.

Thanks for any tips, advice!

Comment: If you do not have access to the page, and the page doesn't support that, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: what are you trying to do with that `fname` parameter? how should it work?

Comment: I just want that info to appear in the form. I don't see why it wouldn't support that as it already sets values for hidden inputs like the pin number. Why won't it set the value for an input that's not hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of parameters in the query string is not important, but as "blockhead" above says, you cannot pre-fill the page if its author has not allowed you to do so.

The PHP behind the page can generate the HTML form according to whatever logic the programmer chooses; it will not automatically pre-fill the input fields from the query string unless the code explicitly prints out that data.

It may be that the programmer behind that page just didn't consider the possibility, or they may have deliberately avoided it for security or technical reasons.

Comment: Is there any other ways of achieving this effect? By using my own PHP in the website that generates the link, perhaps?

Comment: How you generate the link will not make any difference - the website will still see the same link. The only thing you could do would be to make a form that pretends to be their "final step" form, and never show the real form at all. Whether this is easy, or even possible, is down to how they've built the form. At the end of the day, you can't control the functionality of their website. Maybe ask them if they'd be willing to help you?